# Shell/Bash + expect script based on input list

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, expect

I'm trying to run a shell script that execute an expect script based on an input list (IP Addresses), but in parallel.

Unfortunately I didn't understood how to achieve it, below my working script that execute the expect script sequentially on each IP contained in the list.

```js
#!/bin/bash

HOST="$1"
USER="user"
PASS="password"

OUT="checkversion.csv"

rm -rf $OUT
touch $OUT

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

echo "Script started at $NOW"

for i in `cat $1`
do
        SCRIPT=$(expect -c "
                spawn ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -c 3des-cbc -c aes128-cbc -c aes192-cbc -c aes256-cbc -c aes128-ctr -c aes192-ctr -c aes256-ctr $USER@$i
                match_max 100000
                expect \"*?assword:*\"
                send -- \"$PASS\r\"
                expect \"*>*\"
                send -- \"start shell\"
                send -- \"\r\"
                expect \"*%*\"
                send -- \"exit\"
                send -- \"\r\"
                expect \"*>*\"
                send -- \"exit\"
                send -- \"\r\"
        ")

VERSION=`echo "$SCRIPT" | grep JUNOS | grep -v WARNING | grep -v possible | grep -v recover`
echo "$i;$VERSION" >> $OUT
done

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
echo "script finished at $NOW - note any errors above"
```

Could you please help me in found a method to run it in parallel and speedup the process?

Thanks

Comment: buut why not copy your public ssh key to machines so that you don't have to type password? And use ansible, it's a tool for that.

Comment: In that env I can't use ansible or using authentication by ssh key...

Comment: Sure. Then why not `sshpass`?

Comment: Just wondering: You set the variable `HOST` but never use it. What is the purpose of this variable?

Comment: I omitted some parts of the script :-)

Comment: [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing your script as follow:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

HOST="$1"
USER="user"
PASS="password"

OUT="checkversion.csv"

rm -rf $OUT
touch $OUT

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

echo "Script started at $NOW"

function runSSH {
    PARAM=$1
    SCRIPT=$(expect -c "
            spawn ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -c 3des-cbc -c aes128-cbc -c aes192-cbc -c aes256-cbc -c aes128-ctr -c aes192-ctr -c aes256-ctr $USER@$PARAM
            match_max 100000
            expect \"*?assword:*\"
            send -- \"$PASS\r\"
            expect \"*>*\"
            send -- \"start shell\"
            send -- \"\r\"
            expect \"*%*\"
            send -- \"exit\"
            send -- \"\r\"
            expect \"*>*\"
            send -- \"exit\"
            send -- \"\r\"
    ")

    VERSION=`echo "$SCRIPT" | grep JUNOS | grep -v WARNING | grep -v possible | grep -v recover`
    echo "$PARAM;$VERSION" >> $OUT
}

for i in `cat $1`; do
  # Run SSH in background
  runSSH $i &
done

# Wait for background processes to finish...
wait

NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
echo "script finished at $NOW - note any errors above"
```

Comment: It return an error when I ran it

send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send -- "password\r""

Comment: This an issue related to your command that you have to solve on your own. I proposed you a bash pattern to spawn parallel tasks and wait for then to terminate. ;)

Comment: Try passing the hostname to the function: `runSSH "$i" &`

Comment: Sorry, I missed it! :)